# Calibrating SABR -- Can I calibrate the forward like any other parameter?

Tags: options, interest-rates, derivatives, sabr

Essentially the title to the above. I am using SABR to price caps and floors (as well as options on SOFR futures). I currently have two calibration techniques, the first calibrates based on rho and nu (using these to calculate alpha), and the second calibrates all 3 at the same time. I also use a fixed beta.

As I understand, the forward is an input but not a parameter of the model, and I have noticed I can get better fits when I alter the forward. Therefore I am wondering what would happen in practice if I calibrate/move the forward to generate better fits; does this have effects mathematically I have not considered on delta/vega/other risk metrics? The market I am looking at has forwards/ATMs that don't lend themselves to the normal SABR model's natural shape, i.e. generating a parabolic shape around the forward.

[image: Example SABR]

Ignore the legend, but the green is SABR, red is implied market vols, and yellow is ATM vol.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bit like measuring someone's height by asking them to kneel because your tape measure is too short.

As you say, the parameters are numerical variables input to the model. Forwards, ATM vol, skew ...etc are *market observables* you are trying to calibrate your model to. Changing the forward will change what you're attempting to model.

Comment: This makes sense to me. My only question is given that the normal SABR model generates a parabolic shape around the origin (the forward), if I am in a market that has a forward not close to the strike of the lowest vol at that particular expiry, would it not make sense to alter the forward to generate a better fit? Ignore the legend to the plot I'll attach below, but the green is SABR, reds are implied market vols and yellow is the ATM strike.

Comment: The market smile u've plotted (reds) show that off strike (otm) puts close to the fwd have lower vol than the atm, right? Sabr is just matching that (with what looks to be a decent fit). i don't know why you think there should be a "parabolic shape" around the atmfwd - that's not what your market data shows.